# Full width elements within wrapper and container

Tags: html, css

*This is just a general question prior to the development, hence no code provided.

I want a div in the middle of my site to have a background width of 100% in order to go all the way across the screen, but this div is INSIDE the wrapper/container (of which has a 980px width) so it's restricted as normal to the regular content width.

How can this happen without ending wrapper and container, creating the full width div, then making a new set of wrapper/container divs? As w3 validator states to me I should have these particular div's more than once.

Comment: If you want your background to go all the way across the screen, why not just apply it to the <body>?

Comment: Pretty much ^this. It makes no sense to apply a background image to a smaller element on your page, rather than on the outermost element, which would be your body.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you want without examples, but you may want to try something like this:

```
<style>
#width980{width:980px;height:200px;margin:0 auto;background:#aaa;}
#fullwidth{height:100px;background:#000;position:absolute;left:0;top:50px;right:0;color:#fff;}
</style>
<div id="width980">
    width980
<div id="fullwidth">
    fullwidth
</div>
</div>
```

Here, I made you a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wde8W/